# Query to get un-accepted answers, where OP has been active recently

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to get a list of my own un-accepted answers, where the OP have been active during the last week.

How can I write such a query on SEDE?

Is it even possible to query a user's activity on a site?

Comment: I hope such questions is on topic here, I’m sorry if it’s not :)

Comment: SEDE questions are indeed on-topic. The SEDE tour even points you directly here (to MSE) for any questions about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with SEDE is that data is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning. So 'active during the last week' is going to be tough (depending on when you run the query). That said, [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/1174279/unaccepted-answers-to-questions-by-recently-active-users) is close to what you're looking for. You'll need your user ID and a date before last Sunday, e.g. 2019-12-01:

[image]

Comment: I would have expected that join with users to be on the owneruserid of the answers. The OP probably knows when he was last active

Comment: @rene Jdrupal has accepted [all but 1 of his answered questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/72672/jdrupal?tab=questions). It's more logical that he's looking for his *own* unaccepted answers to questions by recently active users.

Comment: @Glorfindel You’re correct. That’s what I want :)

Comment: How can I filter the results to only show answers where score is > 0, thanks :)

Comment: @Jdrupal that's not too difficult, just add `AND a.Score > 0` to the `WHERE` clause. You can [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/fork/1174279) the query to do so. FYI, you might be interested in the [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).